# Delphi +Firedac and network connection error

Tags: mysql, delphi, firedac

My app is working with MySQL database, to connection I'm using FireDAC components. Last time I have got a network problem, I test it and it is looks like (time to time) it losing 4 ping request. My app return me error: "[FireDAC][Phys][MySQL] Lost connection to MySQL server during query". Now the question: setting fdconnection.TFDUpdateOptions.LockWait to true (default is false) will resolve my problem or make new problems?

Answer (score 1):

`TFDUpdateOptions.LockWait` has no effect on your connection to the database. It determines what happens when a record lock can't be obtained immediately. The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FireDAC.Stan.Option.TFDUpdateOptions.LockWait) says it pretty clearly:

> Use the LockWait property to control whether FireDAC should wait while the pessimistic lock is acquired (True), or return the error immediately (False) if the record is already locked. The default value is False.
>
> The LockWait property is used only if LockMode = lmPessimistic.

FireDAC can't wait to get a lock if it loses the connection, as clearly there is no way to either request the lock or determine if it was obtained. Therefore, changing `LockWait` will not change the lost connection issue, and it may slow many other operations against the data.

The only solution to your lost ping requests is to fix your network connection so it stops dropping packets. Simply randomly changing options on `TFDConnection` isn't going to fix networking issues.

Comment: I surprise you - it worked. Now when connection is back, application is no longer 'hanging'